# Leave animation on ng-include with dynamic source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate, angularjs-ng-include

I have a ng-include which is loading content based on a dynamic url (working as expected).

```
<ng-include class="my-content-area" src="templateUrl"></ng-include>
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to animate the `enter` and `leave` of the content (according to the angular docs, those are the two events ng-include provides for animating on).

```
.my-content-area.ng-enter, 
.my-content-area.ng-leave {
  transition: all 500ms;
}    
.my-content-area.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
}
.my-content-area.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}    
.my-content-area.ng-leave {
  opacity:1;
}
.my-content-area.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

The `enter` is working as expected, but the `leave` is not. I am just seeing the content disappear immediately (not fade out) when the `templateUrl` is changed in my controller.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Chrome 31 and Angular 1.2

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLdyVRLz09ADKFfgA2To) with dynamic content, and it works fine.
Try to check it.
I think your problem could be related to the container or the position of the elements.
The initial code was taken [from here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-nginclude-ngview-and-ngif). There you can find more details about animations in angularjs 1.2+.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
.my-content-area.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms; /* Safari/Chrome */
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

Comment: i've tried that. the enter animation is working fine, but the leave isn't. I believe the issue is tied to the fact that it's a dynamic source, not the css (since the enter animations working).